# How do you find Discord.exe using python?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to find the Discord.exe using python so I can start it automatically,
the problem is the only solutions I've found is to get the full path, which it changes quite a bit,
meaning I'd have to update my code every single time Discord updates.

Comment: Then scan through the entire hard drive looking for a file matching the app name

Comment: What does "which it changes quite a bit" mean?

Comment: I was asking how would you go of finding it

Comment: the discord version changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to the discord root folder, which is constant, in windows it'll be something like *C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Local\Discord*, than you can use `os.walk(".")`, it'll return a generator to all the folders down the folder tree, so you can convert this into a list using `list(os.walk("."))`, as yo only want the folders on your current locantion you use the 0th index of this list, and as you want the folders you'll get the second index, the result will be this `list(os.walk("."))[0][1]`, now you just need to find the folder that the executable is located which is called "app-*version*", so we can do a simple iteration to grab this folder, in the and the code will be something like:

```
#code to reach root folder
folders = list(os.walk("."))[0][1]
folder = ""
for f in folders:
    if f[:3] == "app":
        folder = f
#navigate to folder and execute the Discord.exe
```

Comment: list(os.walk(".")) seems to only return the things that are in the folder that the .py is in

Comment: also does it return a string ? how would i go of running it

Comment: so list(os.walk(".")) returns what is in the folder your located, that's why you should navigate to the Discord folder before casting it, or you could simply replace the "." with the discord path, and after finding the name of the folder you append it to the string that defines the path and you have the path to the executable

Comment: sorry, im new to python
i don't understand

Comment: alright so i found a function that let's me get the start of the path, than i use this list function to get the app-[version numbers] name, than i finish it off with a \Discord.exe
thanks for the help!